# Need to convert Mouse events to Touch Events for mobile using HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mouseevent, touch-event

Basically I want the mouseevents above to work on mobile through the use of touchevents. There is some code in there to change the color on each click as well. I 'm hoping that it's as easy as binding the touchevents to the mouseevents, but in my trial and error I  still can't get it to work.

Any help with this would be amazing!

Here is the code that i'm working with:

```js
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// some hotfixes... ( ≖_≖)
document.body.style.margin = 0;
canvas.style.position = 'relative';

// get canvas 2D context and set him correct size
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
resize();

// last known position
var pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };

const cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
cvs.addEventListener('mousedown', getRandomInt);

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
document.addEventListener('mousemove',  draw);
document.addEventListener('mousedown',  setPosition);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter',  setPosition);


function getRandomInt() {
  window.randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3));
}

// new position from mouse event
function setPosition(e) {
  pos.x = e.clientX;
  pos.y = e.clientY;
}

// resize canvas
function resize() {
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function draw(e) {
  // mouse left button must be pressed
  if (e.buttons !== 1) return;

  var color = '';

  switch (window.randInt) {
    case 1: 
      color = 'green';
      break;
    case 2: 
      color = 'red';
      break;
    case 0:
      color = 'blue';
      break;
  }

  ctx.beginPath(); // begin

  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;

  ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y); // from
  setPosition(e);
  ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y); // to

  ctx.stroke(); // draw it!
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it **is** as easy as listening for both - touch and mouse - events.
The `touchstart` event is the `mousedown`, the `touchmove` the `mousemove` and  lastly `touchend` is the `mouseup` equivalent.

Theoretically you could simply add the same callback functions to all of these listeners. The only problem is you can't directly query the 'mouse' position using the `event.clientX` property inside the callback function. That's because there can be multiple touches while there is always just a single mouse event. To keep track of the touches, those are stored in a `TouchList` - more or less an array - which is the `.touches` property of the event.

So we need to make a distinction between a mouse and a touch event inside the callback function:

- If it's a touch use `event.touches[0].clientX`
- If it's a mouse event use `event.clientX`

Here's an example based on your code:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.id = "canvas";
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

document.body.style.margin = 0;
canvas.style.position = 'relative';

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
resize();

var pos = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
var buttonDown = false;

const cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
cvs.addEventListener('mousedown', getRandomInt);
cvs.addEventListener('touchstart', getRandomInt);

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', released);

document.addEventListener('touchstart', setPosition);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', draw);
document.addEventListener('touchend', released);

function getRandomInt() {
  window.randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3));
}

function released(e) {
  buttonDown = false;
}

function setPosition(e) {
  if (e.type == "touchstart" || e.type == "mousedown") {
    buttonDown = true;
  }
  if (e.type == "touchstart" || e.type == "touchmove") {
    pos.x = e.touches[0].clientX;
    pos.y = e.touches[0].clientY;
  } else {
    pos.x = e.clientX;
    pos.y = e.clientY;
  }
}

function resize() {
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function draw(e) {
  if (!buttonDown) return;

  var color = '';

  switch (window.randInt) {
    case 1:
      color = 'green';
      break;
    case 2:
      color = 'red';
      break;
    case 0:
      color = 'blue';
      break;
  }

  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;

  ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
  setPosition(e);
  ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);

  ctx.stroke();
}
```